# Nested try catch in PHP

Tags: php, nested, try-catch

Consider:

```
try{
    class MyException extends Exception{}
    try{
        throw new MyException;
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        echo "1:";
        throw $e;
    }
    catch(MyException $e){
        echo "2:";
        throw $e;
    }
}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo get_class($e);
}
```

I am confused with this try and catch. I am expecting a `2:MyException` result because of the second `try throw MyException`. But the actual result is `1:MyException`. What is the explanation?

Comment: You should use the main Exception as last option. So swap first and second catch blocks.

Answer (score 22):

`MyException` extends `Exception`, so `Exception` is more general than `MyException`, and the first `catch` block will catch it. If you want to catch `MyException` you need to reverse the order of the `catch` blocks:

```
class MyException extends Exception{}

try {
 try {
   throw new MyException;
 } catch(MyException $e){
   echo "2:";
   throw $e;
 } catch(Exception $e){
   echo "1:";
   throw $e;
 }
}catch(Exception $e){
echo get_class($e);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The first catch-block catches everything of the 'Exception' class. Since your MyException extends the Exception-class, the MyException is caught in this first catch-block.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you check the classname and handle it accordingly.

```
class MyException extends Exception {}

try {
    throw new MyException;
}
catch (Exception $ex){
    switch (get_class ($ex)) {

       case "MyException" :
           // Do whatever you want to do for MyException
           break;

       default:
           // Do whatever you want to do for Exception
           break;
   }
   throw $ex;
}
```